# ¿Como posicionar una imagen a la izquierda de un texto en función a su longitud?

Tags: html5, css3

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven en el screenshot superior yo quiero que el svg que tengo ahí se posicione ciertos pixeles a la izquierda según la longitud del texto que tenga el Username. Ya que hasta ahora he estado utilizando solamente position: absolute y le he dado las coordenadas manualmente.

Este sería mi html:

```
    <header id="cabecera">
    <h3 id="user">Username</h3>

    <svg id="config" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:a="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeSVGViewerExtensions/3.0/" x="0px" y="0px" width="27.8px" height="27.8px" viewBox="0 0 27.8 27.8" style="enable-background:new 0 0 27.8 27.8;" xml:space="preserve">
        <a xlink:href="config.html">
            <style type="text/css">
                .st0 {
                    fill: #67C6EF;
                }
            </style>
            <defs>
            </defs>
            <circle id="XMLID_1_" class="st0" cx="13.9" cy="13.9" r="13.9" />
            <polygon points="13.9,21.2 20.6,9.6 7.2,9.6 13.9,21.2 20.6,9.6 7.2,9.6 " />
        </a>
    </svg>


</header>
```

y este sería mi css:

```
#cabecera {
    background-color: #50514F;
    height: 3.5%;
    min-height: 30px;
}

#cabecera #user {
    padding: 3px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: right;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#config
/* El ícono debe moverse en función al username (position: relative) */
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    right: 100px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}

#config:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar `float:right` con el orden que tienes actualmente **usuario**->**imagen** funcionara bien y es una solucion solo con CSS

```
#cabecera * { //todos los hijos de cabecera
  float:right; //se alinean a la derecha
}
```

Aunque como tienes una imagen y un encabezado valdra tambien quitar el margen para que se muestre adecuadamente

```css
#cabecera * {
  float:right;
  margin:0;
}

#cabecera {
    background-color: #50514F;
    height: 3.5%;
    min-height: 30px;
}

#cabecera #user {
    padding: 3px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: right;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<header id="cabecera">
    
<h3 id="user">Usuariooooooooooo</h3>
    <svg id="config" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:a="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeSVGViewerExtensions/3.0/" x="0px" y="0px" width="27.8px" height="27.8px" viewBox="0 0 27.8 27.8" style="enable-background:new 0 0 27.8 27.8;" xml:space="preserve">
        <a xlink:href="config.html">
            <style type="text/css">
                .st0 {
                    fill: #67C6EF;
                }
            </style>
            <defs>
            </defs>
            <circle id="XMLID_1_" class="st0" cx="13.9" cy="13.9" r="13.9" />
            <polygon points="13.9,21.2 20.6,9.6 7.2,9.6 13.9,21.2 20.6,9.6 7.2,9.6 " />
        </a>
    </svg>
    

</header>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias jasilva!!

Comment: @jasilva Tu respuesta funciona pero el uso del selector universal(*) como lo pusiste(a la extrema derecha) no es recomendado. Mira [no uses el selector universal](https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/Disallow-universal-selector). Los navegadores evalúan de derecha a izquierda asi que eso inicialmente seleccionará todos los elementos lo cual es muy malo para el rendimiento.

Answer (score 0):

Los elementos normalmente se alinean a la izquierda como si tuvieran un `float:left` así que tu div que los contiene basta con que alines a la derecha con un `float:right` a sus elementos, pero estos deben aparecer en órden inverso.

```css
#barra {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 100%;
}
#simbolo {
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
#nombre {
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="barra">
  <div id="nombre">naksndlaskndlkanslkdnsalkdnalsdfsdfsdfsdfsfsdfsdfdsfdsfksndlkansldsd</div>
  <div id="simbolo">*</div>
</div>
```